# How to avoid a "can be fast-forwarded" message after a git reset --hard <sha1>?

Tags: git

I've searched through a lot of the posts on `git reset --hard <commit>` and I reset a prematurely merged branch to the state a commit back a bit in the history. The current state of "master" looks good but `git status` says that my local branch is behind origin/master by 24 commits and can be fast-forwarded. I cannot push without first merging origin/master again. Is there a way to skip those commits and say "I don't want them"?

This is a central repo setup and one of my coworkers merged his long-running dev branch with master on accident and couldn't figure out how to backtrack, so I was trying to do it for him.

Recap of commands (from memory, it's been a two day ordeal)

Found out the mistake when I fetched and checked master, informed coworker. He couldn't get it reset so...
I did

```
git merge master origin/master
git reset --hard <commit_I_wanted>
git push # is rejected
git status # gives me the "behind by x commits, can be fast-forwarded" message
```

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ***certain*** that your git history is ***the correct*** version and your coworkers have not made any changes then you can use this command:

```
git push --force
```

In the future, use `git revert` instead which makes a new commit that undoes changes instead of rewriting history.

Again, git push --force will rewrite history on the remote end. You have been warned.

Comment: Okay, I'll think that through. I didn't use revert because I read that it would be difficult (impossible?) to later on merge that development branch in. What I read (in several places) said that revert removes the changes but appears to git that the changes in the branch have been merged, so it won't merge them again.

Comment: What if they have made changes to and pushed (for backup purposes) other branches that I haven't touched? If I make sure I fetch and merge each of those branches, then I'll okay, right?

Comment: Do git push -f origin <branch to overwrite> and then you can safely fetch and merge those other branches into your local "<branch to overwrite>" and then push again.